# XPath to select n-th until last child?

Tags: xpath

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>I do NOT want this</div>
  <div>but I want this</div>        <--------- 2
  <div>and this</div>
  <!-- many more entries -->
  <div>and also this last one</div> <--------- last one
</div>
```

Using XPath I want to select all `div/div[from 2 until last one]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the position method, this should work for you

```
//div/div[position() > 1]
```